# Google Analytics Query Explorer Run Query Error

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the query explorer to generate some queries based on the inputs. It was working fine since yesterday. When I click on the Run Query button today, I'm getting this error: "Ack! There was an error () Cannot read property 'access_token' of null". 
I tried to run the query using the Outh 2.0 Playground, there's no issue with the generated token.

Any Idea as to why this might be happening ?

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a temporary issue and has been fixed now. See this [bug report](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/issues/125) for more details.